# location in the background does not work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, locationmanager

I am developing a code that should get my location every 10 minutes and salvation in CoreData. When I walk into background with conectavo app to xcode can not see the log that the service is running, but when I go out walking the streets he simply not saved or saved too few times.

This is part of my code that should do this function.See save in codeData:

```
var saveLocationInterval = 60.0

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler(nil)
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(saveLocationInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.saveLocation), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

        locationController.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        saveLocation()
    }

func saveLocation(){
        print("======")
        let logUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("LOG_GPS", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext) as! LOG_GPS

        if locationController.location == nil{
            logUser.latitude = ""
            logUser.longitude = ""
        } else {
            logUser.latitude = "\(locationController.location!.coordinate.latitude)"
            logUser.longitude = "\(locationController.location!.coordinate.longitude)"
        }

        logUser.velocidade = userSpeed > 0 ? Int(userSpeed) : 0
        logUser.address = "\(userSpeed)"

        if _usuario.chave != nil {
            logUser.chave_usuario = "\(_usuario.chave!)"
        }
        if _empresa.chave != nil {
            logUser.chave_licenca = "\(_empresa.chave!)"
        }

        print("localizaçao salva no bd \(logUser.latitude)")
        let date = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"
        let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
        logUser.data = dateString
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
        }
    }
```

Another major error in my code I can not solve is the User's speed. In the method the low I'm trying to save your speed in a variable and then save the CoreData however this is me always returning a negative value:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
        var speed: CLLocationSpeed = CLLocationSpeed()
        speed = newLocation.speed
        print(speed * 3.6)
        userSpeed = speed * 3.6
    }
```

[this is my background mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvAfA.png)

Comment: did you set UIBackgroundModes?

Comment: I post a Screen shot

Comment: I think I solved your issue; comment below my answer to tell me if it works or not!

Comment: Ohmigod, I just realized that I answered this same question months ago...I'm so sorry for not remembering that earlier!! Anyway, this will definitely solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524644/background-location-tracking-not-working-on-physical-device-swift/36524652#36524652 I will add it to my answer.

Comment: So my final answer, which will definitely do it for you, has been added to my answer below (in `possible solution 2`). Please let me know how well it works!! (and sorry again for not remembering this trick sooner.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Possible solution 1**

You need a key in your `Info.plist` that describes why your app needs background location.

Go to your `Info.plist`, find the `Bundle Version` key and click the `+` that appears when you hover over that. Then add the key `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, set it to be a string, and set the value as whatever you want the description to be, like "We need your location in the background so we share your location with friends."

Now your app should work. If it doesn't....

**Possible solution 2 (more likely solution if you know what you're doing)**

With iOS 9, Apple made it so that apps on physical devices need a special line of code to run location services in the background. The change was not widely reported on (if at all?) but I managed to figure this one out a while ago. Here's what you need to do to get location services working in the background on physical devices again:

In your main location tracking view controller's `ViewDidLoad` put...

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
     locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
} else {
    // You don't need anything else on earlier versions.
}
```

This will (mysteriously enough) likely be all you need to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I do this and now I will make some tests. If it works I live here. But thank you anyway.

Comment: @breno Great. Let me know if it works, and be sure to hit the checkmark if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Leave it to me. Thank you =D

Comment: I did the tests and found that even then the error still continues. At one point the ipad simply to recording the information in the database.

Comment: Ok, then you're code's probably wrong. Try doing the location part of [this background modes tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial) then using that code in your project. That should do the trick.

Comment: @breno How'd this turn out?

Comment: I have not solved my problem. left aside for the moment but but if you get one update answer here.

Comment: @breno In case you still don't realize I updated my answer, I did :). Check it out, it'll solve your problem (and give it the checkmark if it does fix your issue).

Comment: I put this code in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but did not work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @breno If any location-tracking view controller has a `viewdidload`, try putting it there instead of in the App Delegate.